# Android - Adding item to ListView from another Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

First of all, I've searched on many other posts and still not found a fix for it.

`MainActivity` contains a `ListView` and an `ImageButton` that takes to `AddActivity`.
This `AddActivity` has got a `EditText` (`nameAddInput`) and a `Button`(`addButton`).

Despite clicking this `Button`, the `ListView` in `MainActivity` remains empty... Don't understand why...

Here is the the **code of MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 0;

private ListView list;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemsList);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.listview_style1, android.R.id.text1, arrayList);
}

public void onClickAddButton(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 2);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            addNewItem();
        }
    }
}

public void addNewItem() {
    Bundle addNameInfo = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(addNameInfo == null)
        return;
    String nameInput = addNameInfo.getString("nameInput");
    arrayList.add(nameInput);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

In **xml file of MainActivity** in the ImageButton: `android:onClick="onClickAddButton"`

The **code of AddActivity**:

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
}

public void backToMain(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    EditText nameAddInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameAddInput);
    String userNameText = nameAddInput.getText().toString();
    i.putExtra("nameInput", userNameText);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();
}
```

}

In **xml file of AddActivity** in the Button: `android:onClick="backToMain"`

Hope someone can help!!
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getIntent() returns you the intent that launched MainActivity, not the one you set in backInMain

Try the "data" variable passed to you in onActivityResult?

Also change to

```
startActivityForResult(i, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

I'd also suggest you rename that variable

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've tried like @termigrator said and still not working.

Comment: In addition to above, you called startActivityForResult(x, 2) (ie request code = 2) but in your onActivityResult callback, you check the code against PICK_CONTACT_CODE which you defined as 0. These numbers need to be equal.

Answer (score 0):

set adapter  just in onCreate  and just call notifyDataSetChanged in addNewItem method.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

'arrayList.add(nameInput);
arrayList.add(currentSize++, nameInput);
list.setAdapter(adapter);'

Make this in onCreate method and only 'adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();' in 'addNewItem()' ?

Answer (score 0):

the resulting value is returned in the `Intent data`-Parameter of the onActivityResult function, not in the intent-member of the mainActivity.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent    data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            addNewItem(data.getExtras().getString("nameInput");
       }
   }
}
...
public void addNewItem(String newItem)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

'public void addNewItem(String nameInput) {
 arrayList.add(nameInput);
 list.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}'

Tried to change 'onActivityResult(...)' method and this one above and it is still not working..